# Desktop App Downloader and Installer

Tags: windows-installer

I have a 50MB desktop application.

I'm looking for some kind of a small 100-500KB app loader that will basically download and install my application on user's computer.

I want this because i think that if i can get a user to download the 100kb loader then they're more likely to finish the full 50MB download and install.

Does anybody know of any services or packages out there that can do this?

Comment: Actually I can see no difference: in either way users have to download the full 50MB. Personally I'd prefer to download the real installer myself. On the other hand, it makes sense to provide a small application which downloads the installer if your application is separated into different features and users can select to install only features they want; in this case that small application downloads and installs the selected components thus reducing the download size.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921579/google-chrome-like-downloader-and-installer

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create an installer for your application, preferably an MSI package. Here is a list of setup tools: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

After that, you can use a simple EXE bootstrapper which downloads and launches the installation package. Most commercial setup tools offer this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I know the following:

- [Google Omaha](http://code.google.com/p/omaha/)
- [AdvancedInstaller](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/)
- [Somoto BetterInstaller](http://betterinstaller.somotoinc.com/) (adds recommendations as well from which you can make money)
- [Ignite](http://www.opencandy.com/developers/ignite/) (not available yet)

You could possibly also create your own quite easily using for example the [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/),  [NSIS](http://wixtoolset.org/) or [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).